# Gtk.TreeView:Python How to set background color row selected when lost focus of treeview

Tags: python, colors, gtktreeview

I have trouble in python gtk.TreeView: when a row selected on treeview it has background Blue, and then after that I changed focus to another object (example textbox) then the row was selected changed color to gray. I don't want change it to gray, I want it to still Blue. Is there any help.
Could you please help me?
Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've solved it with the CSS feature of gtk programs.
the css to manage the selection of row is

```
GtkTreeView row:selected {\
        background: #f07746;\
        color: #ffffff;\
    }\
```

The background will override the gray effect when you lose the focus.
In your program you can apply the custom style with

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, CSS, -1, NULL);
```

(C language, but I can imagine you can find the equivalent in python)

Hope it helps even if it is a late answer. Can